# Need help understanding css3 gradients and background-repeat

Tags: css, sass, gradient, background-repeat

I've got a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/CWSpear/pen/8-bit/4) here where I'm trying to make my little 8-bit dude into CSS3.

On line 89, I start working on the beard. But it's not quite right.

It's currently repeating x and y, but it's making vertical stripes instead of the polka-dot effect I'm going for. If you uncomment line 98 (`background-repeat:repeat-x;`), then you'll see it has the right pattern, but then it doesn't repeat vertically (obviously) (I'd like the div to be any height and this would still work, ya know?). I want that pattern to repeat correctly in both directions. It seems to overlap or something when it has repeat or repeat-y turned on.

In the `color-stops()`, I originally used `transparent` instead of the `$face` color, but it made the whole thing red instead.

To know what I'm trying to achieve, please reference my Avatar on this site.

[edit] I think it's extra complicated because my pattern isn't a straight checkered pattern. Here's a close-up of the minimum pattern that repeats:

[image]

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Not really. This is what I ended up doing, but it was less than ideal: http://codepen.io/CWSpear/pen/8-bit/5. But it does work. You can change the `$size` to a multiple of 120 and it scales nicely.

Comment: Looks good. I asked because I thought I had found the solution. It turned out I didn't. I'll still keep thinking about it though.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I think this is good enough for now for the beard. Someday, I'll figure out the shirt. I don't care if it's not perfect, but something plaid, heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of the backgrounds is completely covering the other. The others simply not being seen. I'll try and figure out how I'd do it.

**Update**
So.. it's not that easy. The only way I imagine as being possible to do is by using diagonal gradients as Lea Verou did here - http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#checkerboard

The problem is, if you shrink the sizes too much it won't look perfect - here's a tinkerbin with me doing so - http://tinkerbin.com/MQaHKuJI

Comment: Yeah, I think it's repeating every 1 px, but I want it to repeat every 4 pixels. Even if I had 4 "rows" in my gradient (and 4 background-positions), that wouldn't do it (I tried).

Comment: I'm trying to make it work, but it's tough because it's not a straight-up checked pattern.

Comment: I found a better approach than gradients: http://codepen.io/blazeeboy/pen/bCaLE. But I marked you as correct since you did help me better understand it, etc.

Comment: Completely forgot about this ;) Yes, I've also come across this technique. Box-shadows makes it very much easier. That image to css converter is pretty cool man! I'll definitely be using it if it's there to use. Great job!

Comment: I've found this - http://www.patternify.com/ - which is pretty cool, and I had no idea about. Makes creating this kind of pattern extremely easy and brings no extra image http request. http://ptrn.it/SNxX5L -> your pattern

Comment: That tool is cool. I was hoping to do pure css without images, and even though it's just the raw image data in the CSS and not an additional request, it feels like cheating, haha. Thanks for the share, though. The `box-shadow` approach sounds like the way to go in this instance.